# How to reduce chair squeak

Tags: furniture

I have an office chair with five wheels.  When you lean forward or back, it creaks.  What can be done to eliminate the creak?

Comment: I find a drop of oil on the pivot points eliminate the squeaking and creaking and I am a big guy it should work for you also.

Comment: Is there a weight limit on the chair?  Should be labeled under chair. And the high end chairs , have fittings for  special lube mine was a blue grease.

Comment: @RobertMoody - It was a low end chair and I replaced it.  But thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To find the exact spot where the squeak originates, use a meter-long piece of 3/4" heater hose or vinyl tubing. While you squeak the chair, your assistant uses the tubing like a stethoscope to find the loudest point under the chair.
Once you have found the point, mark it with a pen or chalk. It could be metal-to-metal, metal-to-plastic, or plastic-to-plastic. It could be in the center support, in an adjustment plate, or in the seat bottom or back.
You could spray something, rub a wax crayon, or sprinkle powder, depending on the exact location. Good luck, and keep trying.